# TreeView component by LinearLayout - out of memory error

Tags: android, memory-management, android-linearlayout, out-of-memory

I make a treeview component by `LinearLayout` base. But when inner items count is very large android close it by out of memory error.
I used only 3 bitmap by 3kb size in each items.

How can I reduce memory using of my component (`LinearLayout`) I know `ListView` has `scrollingCache` but I use `LinearLayout` ?
Can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: I assume that `TreeView` is something like a `ListView` made by you. If my assumption is correct then my answer is: Do you have implemented a views recycle system in your `TreeView`?

Comment: How can i recycle view (I have TextView)? I know 'bitmap' has same method.But I catch my only 3 bitmaps.

Comment: If you have any code you can post it and i'll try to help you with it. Anyway can i ask you why you don't extends `ListView` in your custom `TreeView`?

Comment: It take a lot of time ,I have not time.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` use a system that initialize only the row(view) that are visible to the user. When a row in not visible anymore it doesn't get destroyed, but it is used to inflate the layout of the next view that will be visible. With this system you have to save in memory only for the object that are visible, even if there is 1000 of item in your list.

[Here you can find a more accurate description of the recycle system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

I think you should also take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). It's a lesson on `ListView` from Google I/O. I find out it is very useful to understand how `ListView` works .

In your case, if you cannot use `ListView`, i think you should implements manually this system. This is pretty hard so the best advice i can give you is to try to create a custom `ListView` that fit your needs and use it.

PS:The method `recycle()` is a bit different, it is used to delete any reference to the `Bitmap` on which you are using the method. This way, the next time the GC run, it will be able to delete from memory the `Bitmap`

Comment: Try to take a look at the [ListView sourcecode](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/3661101005c6527dfd384d0c88c4a3b68ee208af/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java) and see if it help you. Without some of your code i can't do anything more :(. Hope it helps